# Output to Temporary Table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, output-clause

I am trying to use the `OUTPUT` clause *inside a stored procedure* to output to a temporary table the values of an indentity column after an `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID INT
)

INSERT INTO [TableB] OUTPUT INSERTED.ID #Test SELECT * FROM [TableA]
```

However, when I execute this procedure SQL Server shows me the results in a table (correctly) called `Test` but if I write `SELECT * FROM #Test` as the next statement in the stored procedure it shows me nothing. How can I efectively accomplish this?

Answer (score 21):

I think you're missing an `INTO` - try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(ID INT)

INSERT INTO [TableB] 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO #Test 
    SELECT * FROM [TableA]
```

After the list of columns to `OUTPUT`, add an `INTO` before the table name